# Create a page indicator in wp8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, uislider

Hi i am trying to implement the slider as shown in the figure below. It is really easy in web using jquery. But the problem is that i have to implement it in wp8. So any idea how do i make circular rings as marked and then on swipe to the right the ring should get marked. Any code snippet if you have any would be great. 
thanks
                  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this way. This is just a sample.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Hub Name="hub" SectionsInViewChanged="Hub_SectionsInViewChanged" >
        <HubSection Tag="0" Background="Red" />
        <HubSection Tag="1" Background="Blue" />
        <HubSection Tag="2" Background="Green" />
        <HubSection Tag="3" Background="Aqua" />
    </Hub>

    <Grid Width="80" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Name="circle1" Margin="5,0,5,0" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Grid.Column="0" Opacity="1"/>
        <Ellipse Name="circle2" Margin="5,0,5,0" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Ellipse Name="circle3" Margin="5,0,5,0" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Grid.Column="2" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Ellipse Name="circle4" Margin="5,0,5,0" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Grid.Column="3" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and the function for event SectionsInViewChanged in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Hub_SectionsInViewChanged(object sender, SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
        circle1.Opacity = 0.5;
        circle2.Opacity = 0.5;
        circle3.Opacity = 0.5;
        circle4.Opacity = 0.5;
        var tag = hub.SectionsInView[0].Tag.ToString();
        switch(tag)
        {
            case "0":
                circle1.Opacity = 1;
                break;
            case "1":
                circle2.Opacity = 1;
                break;
            case "2":
                circle3.Opacity = 1;
                break;
            case "3":
                circle4.Opacity = 1;
                break;
            default :
                circle1.Opacity = 1;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro . One question can we improve the timing of shift in state of ellipse . it takes a bit more time although its fine  . thanks

Comment: I know what you mean. It is that the event is fired after a transition is over when we swap to the right, but it works in an instant for the swipe to the left. Unfortunately I've met this before and I didn't find a solution for this. However I've seen apps that made this work like a charm so there must be trick for this.